# Apache CXF library detected in ws endpoint deployment

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, soap, cxf

I am trying to deploy my WAR app in Wildfly 10.0.0, and I am running into a common issue :

```
"{\"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services\" => 
{\"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"my-app-ws.war\\\".PARSE\" =>
\"org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"my-app.war\\\"
.PARSE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment \\\"my-app.war\\\"
  Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: 
  WFLYWS0059: Apache CXF library (cxf-core-3.1.4.jar) detected in ws endpoint deployment; 
  either provide a proper deployment replacing embedded libraries with container 
  module dependencies or disable the webservices subsystem for the current deployment adding 
  a proper jboss-deployment-structure.xml descriptor to it. The former approach is 
  recommended, as the latter approach causes most of the webservices Java EE and any JBossWS 
  specific functionality to be disabled.\"}}"
```

Then again I tried to make the CXF dependencies scope provided:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Then I've tried to deploy the WAR archive again, but I run into another problem:

```
"{\"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services\" => {\"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"my-app-ws.war\\\".POST_MODULE\" => \"org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"my-app-ws.war\\\".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \\\"my-app-ws.war\\\"
  Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: 
  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet from [Module \\\"deployment.my-app-ws.war:main\\\" 
  from Service Module Loader]
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet from [Module \\\"deployment.my-app-ws.war:main\\\" 
  from Service Module Loader]\"}}"
```

How can I workaround this issue ?

Comment: Seems you are directly using the Apache CXF, can you share a code snippet with your WS Client / Server ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java EE standard JAX-WS (JBoss uses Apache CXF for implementation of JAX-WS), or disable JBoss's webservice subsystem: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/221654 (if you really need to, but be aware if there are other applications that rely on this)